# How to read specific column data from xlsx and update to js file in python?

Tags: python-2.7, xlsx

```js
// Morris.js Charts sample data for SB Admin template

$(function() {

    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
// Area Chart Resumes
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart-2',
        data: [{
            
        period: '2016-08',
        company0: 524252,
        company1: 0,
        company2: 68076,
        company3: 11745,
        company4: 0,
 company5: 4896,
 
        }],
        });
// Area Chart JDs
    Morris.Area({
        element: 'morris-area-chart',
        data: [{
            
 {
     period: '2016-08',
        company0: 524252,
        company1: 0,
        company2: 68076,
        company3: 11745,
        company4: 0,
 company5: 4896,
 }],
        
    });
```

[image]Problem:

1) First i want to read data from 'Total resumes' column.

2) After reading data,Update those data in .js file according to the name.

If row is empty then update it with 0 value.

This is how .js file structure looks like.

Please refer screen shots for reference

[image]

[image]

Comment: What?  Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I want to read data from xlsx file and update those data in 'morris-data.js' file.

Comment: Can we convert .xlsx file to .csv

Comment: @SHAKEELMOHAMMAD You can..but those data should be update in js file

Comment: @raghavendrat can we know complete js file

Comment: attach file too

Comment: @SHAKEELMOHAMMAD I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is perfect, but it is working

change your .xlsx file to csv  and run below code

```
def generate(company, val):
    if(val == ''):
        val = '0'
    return '\t' + company + ' : ' + val + '\n'
f = open('resume.csv', 'r')
data = f.read().split('\n')
result = ''
for i in range(1, len(data)-1):
    row = data[i].split(',')
    result = result +  generate(row[1], row[4])
print result

js_file = open('data1.js').read()
start = js_file.find('data: [{')
while(start!=-1):
    end = js_file.find('}],', start+1)
    output =  js_file[0:start] + 'data : [{\n' + result + js_file[end:] + '\n\t}],'
    print output
    output_file = open('data1.js', 'w').write(output)
    js_file = open('data1.js').read()
    start = js_file.find('data: [{')
```

only one time it will work, if you want to run next time also

change `start = js_file.find('data: [{')` to `start = js_file.find('data : [{')`

```
output =  js_file[0:start] + 'data : [{\n' + result + js_file[end:] + '\n\t}],'
```

to

```
output =  js_file[0:start] + 'data: [{\n' + result + js_file[end:] + '\n\t}],'
```

observe just i am changing spaces in `data: [` to `data : [`

and if you want again and again change alternatively. Go through the code you will understood i think

my .csv file check it is matching with your's or not

```
s.no,company,total job,cumulative,total resumes,resume cumulate
1,company0,40079,4645,330,4543
2,company1,,,,345
3,company2,23250,5345,68076,3245
4,company3,728,435,11745,3245
5,company4,10,345,4896,345
```

Comment: Partially it worked. I will work on rest..if i need more help i will contact u...thanks

Comment: It updating to js file but values are different ..can u tell me why values are different.                                                                                                    This Output i got: Name of Company : Total Resumes
        company0 : " 9
        company1 :  2 
        company2 : " 2
        company3 : 477 "
        company4 :  5 
        company5 :  6 
        company6 : 0

Comment: Check your .xls format is not perfect, same serial number for company0 and  company1

Comment: It will be like that only always...can u do something for that. I will get excel in that format only always so...if u help me with that it would be great.

Comment: problem with your .xlsx file format, see .csv file of mine, i have attached. make sure that it should be same format. otherwise it will give wrong result

Comment: Ok i will check

Comment: It's worked..thanks..i need one more help.. If in case js file order is changed how to map.. Ex : company1, company3, company0, company4 order is there means how to map.(Note: xlsx format won't change but js file order will change)